# Magento: change layout if category has no products

Tags: magento, layout

I want to change the 2 columns layout of the category page to 1 column when the category is empty. Since I use the left column for layered navigation, and in this case there is no one, the left columns appears blank and doesn't look good.

Any advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across this as I was trying to do exactly the same.  Unfortunately, this solution didn't work, but it pointed me in the right direction.  Final solution was:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Branded3_Emptycategory>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Branded3_Emptycategory>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <branded3_emptycategory>
            <class>Branded3_Emptycategory_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>branded3_emptycategory_resource</resourceModel>
        </branded3_emptycategory>
        <branded3_emptycategory_resource>
            <class>Branded3_Emptycategory_Model_Resource</class>
        </branded3_emptycategory_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <branded3_emptycategory>
            <class>Branded3_Emptycategory_Block</class>
        </branded3_emptycategory>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <branded3_emptycategory>
            <class>Branded3_Emptycategory_Helper</class>
        </branded3_emptycategory>
    </helpers>
</global>

<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
            <observers>
                <branded3_default>
                    <class>branded3_emptycategory/observer</class>
                    <method>zeroproducts</method>
                </branded3_default>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

And an observer:

```
class Branded3_Emptycategory_Model_Observer {

public function zeroproducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $controller   = $observer->getAction();

    //limit to the product view page
    if ($controller->getFullActionName() != 'catalog_category_view')
    {
        return;
    }

    $_productCollection = $observer->getEvent()
        ->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection();

    $products = clone $_productCollection;

    if(!$products->count()):
        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()
                 ->getBlock('root')
                 ->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
    endif;

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a module under app/code/local/Amit/Custommodule
and create  config.xml under app/code/local/Amit/Custommodule/etc/ code and code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <amitcustommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
            </amitcustommodule>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>

        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_default>
                <observers>
                    <amitcustommodule_default>
                        <class>amitcustommodule/observer</class>
                        <method>logCartAdd</method>
                    </amitcustommodule_default>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_default>
                <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_layered>
                <observers>
                    <amitcustommodule_default_2>
                        <class>amitcustommodule/observer</class>
                        <method>logCartAdd</method>
                    </amitcustommodule_default_2>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_layered>
    </events>

    </frontend>
</config>
```

And Observer.php to app/code/local/Amit/Custommodule/Model/

```
 <?php Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer
 public function logCartAdd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

    $_productCollection=$observer->getEvent()
       ->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection();
     if(!$_productCollection->count()): 
    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()
                       ->getBlock('root')
                       ->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');  
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Shall i change method name logCartAdd => mycartadd @Amit